# How to change value of protected variable in parent class function

Tags: php, codeigniter, inheritance

I have 2 classes
    1. user(parent)
    2. validate(child)

in user i authenticate the user,

```
class User extends CI_Controller {
    protected $access = "hii";

    function v_c(){
        $access = $this->model2->getAccess();
        $this->access = $access;
        redirect('user/storelist');
    }

}

class validate extends User{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        print_r($this->access);die;
    }
}
```

instead of giving me access values, in validate class `$this->access` returns 'hii'.
I want to change the value of protected variable in parent class function and then retrieve it in child class?
What am i doing wrong here?
Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: change value here `protected $access = "hii";` which you want

Comment: `v_c()` method __never__ runs. So, `access` property is not changed.

Comment: i want to overwrite the value (hii) in function `v_c()`.

Comment: if i do `print_r($this->access);` in `v_c()` i get correct value, they are not getting passed t0 child class.

Comment: __How__ they will be passed to child class if you don't run `v_c()` method in __child__ class?

Comment: but i m running v_c() in parent class and updating the value in parent class itself, so shouldnt i be getting updated values in child class??

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class User extends CI_Controller {
    protected $access = "hii";

    function v_c(){
        $access = $this->model2->getAccess();
        $this->access = $access;
        redirect('user/storelist');
        return $access;
    }

}

class validate extends User{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        print_r($this->v_c());die;
    }
}
```

Your `$access` variable is protected so you try to `print_r` it like you said but you point to the protected one. On the other hand your `$access` variable inside `v_c` function can be access by returning it inside the function and try to access the function itself and not the variable.

Since you extend your parent class (Users) you can access it's functions and get the returned values from them.

Comment: So why do you create object of parent class in child class?

Comment: Edited my answer thank you for pointing out. i missed the extend part (my bad)

Comment: `this->v_c()` sets value of `access` property. Why return something from it? `access` property is __available__ in child class too.

Comment: But according to OP the value of the protected variable changes inside the function so if i try to return the protected variable itself i will get the starting output and not the modified one coming from         `$access = $this->model2->getAccess();`

Comment: is there no way for me to overwrite the protected variables in my function?? since i have checked multiple times that v_c is being called.. because if i do `print_r($this->access);` in `v_c()` i get updated value.

Comment: The thing is that your variable changes inside your function so if  you don't call the function you will just get the protected value of the variable

Answer (score 0):

You Should change the value `protected $access = " "`